# Filter object by name with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, fetch

I made a request to an endpoint and I get this object, I'm filtering the name like this:

```
fetch('http://endpoint', requestOptions)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((result) => {
  const onlineUsers = result.resource.items[1].onlineUsers >= 1;
  console.log(onlineUsers);
})
.catch((error) => console.log('error', error));
```

This workers, but I just need the result of what is in the key named `Forms`, but there is a possibility that it will change its position, so the `items[1]` it may not work anymore

This is an example of the object I receive:

```
{
  "type": "application/vn+json",
  "resource": {
    "total": 4,
    "itemType": "application",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "Test",
        "onlineUsers": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Forms",
        "onlineUsers": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Users",
        "onlineUsers": 7
      },
      {
        "name": "OnlineUsers",
        "onlineUsers": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  "method": "get",
  "status": "success"
}
```

Is there any way to receive this object and filter by name? Like:

```
if (hasName === "Forms", get onlineUsers) { 
  // Do something
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in your question, you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on your array. Something like that:

```
console.log(
  result.resource.items.filter((item) => item.name === "Forms")
);
```

This will print an array with all items having the name `Forms`. Using your example:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Forms",
    "onlineUsers": 1
  }
]
```

If there is only one item with the name `Forms`, or if you want only the first one, [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) may be a good alternative with a similar syntax:

```
console.log(
  result.resource.items.find((item) => item.name === "Forms")
);
```

This will only print the first found object (or null if none is matching), without the array "pollution":

```
{
  "name": "Forms",
  "onlineUsers": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
result.resource.items.filter((item) => item.name === "Forms")
```

Will filter your objects for you
Note, you will get back an array of all the filtered objects meeting the condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you know there's only one object that matches that name you can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) which will return the first match so you don't necessarily need to iterate over the entire array.

Here's a little general function that might help. Pass in the data, the value of `name`, and the property you want the value of. If there is no match it returns 'No data'.

```js
const data={type:"application/vn+json",resource:{total:4,itemType:"application",items:[{name:"Test",onlineUsers:1},{name:"Forms",onlineUsers:1},{name:"Users",onlineUsers:7},{name:"OnlineUsers",onlineUsers:5}]},method:"get",status:"success"};

function finder(data, name, prop) {
  return data.resource.items.find(item => {
    return item.name === name;
  })?.[prop] || 'No data';
}

console.log(finder(data, 'Forms', 'onlineUsers'));
console.log(finder(data, 'morf', 'onlineUsers'));
console.log(finder(data, 'Users', 'onlineUsers'));
console.log(finder(data, 'Users', 'onlineUser'));
```